# $.ajax does not work in Firefox 4.0.1 and IE9

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-events

Callbacks of `$.ajax` does not work in Firefox 4.0.1 and IE9

I am using this function of jQuery to email contact. Following is the code.

The controller is running normally, indicating that the Javascript is running!
Only `$.ajax` events apparently are not being called.

**Javascript**

```
$(window).ready(function () {
    //Send mail
    $("div.contato-pedidooracao form").submit(function () {
        var dataString = $(this).serialize();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Contato/SendMail",
            data: dataString,
            dataType: "json",
            beforeSend: function () { //Dont Work in IE9 and Firefox!!
                $(".sending").show();
                $(".status").show();
                $(".status > span").show();
                $(".submit > input").attr('disabled', true);
            },
            complete: function () { //Dont Work in IE9 and Firefox!!
                $(".sending").hide();
                $(".message").show();
                $(".status > span").hide();
                $(".submit > input").removeAttr('disabled');
            },
            success: function (data) { //Dont Work in IE9 and Firefox!!
                $(".message").empty();
                $(".message").append("<p>Mensagem enviada com sucesso!</p>");
            },
            error: function () { //Dont Work in IE9 and Firefox!!
                $(".message").empty();
                $(".message").append("<p>Ocorreu um erro ao tentar enviar a mensagem.</p>");
            }
        });
    });
});
```

**Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult SendMail(string name, string phone, string cel, string email, string message)
{
    using (var mail = new MailMessage())
    {
        mail.To.Add("--email--");

        mail.From = new MailAddress("\"" + name + "\" <" + email + ">");
        mail.Subject = "Pedido de Oração - " + name;
        mail.Body = message;
        mail.IsBodyHtml = false;
        new SmtpClient().Send(mail);

    }
    return Json(new { Sucess = true, Message = "Email enviado com sucesso!" });
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="content contato-pedidooracao">
    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        <p>Conte-nos seu pedido</p>
        <div class="inline">
            @Html.Label("name", "Nome:")
            @Html.TextBox("name", "")
        </div>
        <div class="inline">
            @Html.Label("phone", "Telefone:")
            @Html.TextBox("phone", "", new { @class = "phone" })
            @Html.TextBox("cel", "", new { @class = "phone" })
        </div>
        <div class="inline">
            @Html.Label("email", "e-mail:")
            @Html.TextBox("email", "", new { @class = "email" })
        </div>
        <div class="inline">
            @Html.Label("message", "Mensagem:")
            @Html.TextArea("message", "")
        </div>
        
        <div class="status">
            <span>Enviando mensagem:</span><img class="sending" src="@Href("~/Images/ajax-loader2.gif")" alt="Enviando..." />
            <div class="message"></div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="submit">
            <input type="submit" value="Enviar" title="Enviar" />
        </div>
    }
    
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding a preventDefault to your submit function:

```
$("div.contato-pedidooracao form").submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    //rest of your code
```